# Android App not Installing onto Device

Tags: android, upload, installation, emulation, device

So the back story is this:
I can install perfectly fine and run the program on the emulator, but the second I try and install it on my device i get this:

```
[2011-01-08 21:29:36 - girboardpro] Android Launch!
[2011-01-08 21:29:36 - girboardpro] adb is running normally.
[2011-01-08 21:29:36 - girboardpro] Performing com.laytproducts.girboardpro.mainAct activity launch
[2011-01-08 21:29:38 - girboardpro] Uploading girboardpro.apk onto device 'I8975c9b90dc'
[2011-01-08 21:29:46 - girboardpro] Failed to install girboardpro.apk on device 'I8975c9b90dc': timeout
[2011-01-08 21:29:46 - girboardpro] Launch canceled!
```

I have NO idea why.
Nothing pops up on my LogCat, nothing happens on the device...

Hopefully someone can help :)

Thanks,

Brandon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation I would try following things:

- If the application was previously installed and not getting installed again, then from the command prompt run "adb uninstall" package name
- On the phone Settings -> Application -> Development -> Debuggable to true
- Try installing the app from the command prompt `adb install apk.file`
- Restart the device: It has happened with me also, restarting the phone & eclipse solved my problem.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Restarting did not help... still get the error.

also i cant get adb to open to try to install manually

Comment: By saying you cannot open adb what do you  mean? Does "adb devices" command runs and shows the list of devices attached? If not, then might be some problem with the adb.

Comment: the adb command doesnt open at all. Like it wont stay running?

Comment: figured out how to fix my ADB issue... now to the device issue

Comment: Restarting eclipse helped for me.

Answer (score 3):

If unplugging the device and plugging it back in doesn't work, try increasing the upload timeout to something really huge like 20000 ms. It's at Window → Preferences → Android → DDMS → "ADB connection time out (ms)".

Comment: I find I often need to do this if I have any large image files in my res/ or assets/ folders.

Answer (score 1):

I have never personally seen this message, but you should try to use:

```
adb kill-server
```

then try again.  It resets the adb communication link with a phone.  Helps sometimes during debug sessions in development.  In the case of system type files like IME keyboards, you can also try to push the APK to the device using

```
adb push <location_of_apk_on_computer> <future_location_on_phone>
```

then install like a normal APK

```
adb install <location_of_apk>
```

You might also be having trouble with it not uninstalling from the device, so you should try:

```
adb uninstall <fqn_of_program>
```

In your case "com.laytproducts.girboardpro" would seem to be the Fully Qualified Name(fqn)

Comment: My adb wont open... it just does this long sequence of stuff then closes

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the right error message for this answer (I get device not found), but try it anyway:

In order to install an android app on your phone, you need to go to:

Settings->Applications

Set: Unknown Sources to True

Settings->Applications->Development

Set everything to True to get a better debug environment.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Doesn't help.

I added mock locations and Stay Awake and didnt help... still doesnt upload/install